# How does a zero-order hold kernel in a Convolutional Neural Network look like?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, signal-processing

Several papers co-authored by Hitoshi Kiya propose to use a fixed convolutional layer with a zero-order hold kernel to avoid checkerboard artifacts in CNNs. [1, 2, 3]

While there is plenty of literature regarding the zero-order hold model in 1D signal processing I haven't been able to find anything regarding zero-order hold in image processing, especially in the context of a convolutional neural network layer.

The publication [1] proposes in equation (6)

$K^{(d)}_{i,i,:,:}=\begin{cases}
h_0 & (d=0)\\
K^{(d-1)}_{i,i,:,:} * h_0 & (d>1)
\end{cases}$

to convolve the zero-order hold kernel $h _0$  multiple times to obtain a smoothed kernel. Therefore I assume it must be a regular convolutional kernel?

How would such a kernel look like for a transposed convolutional layer with an upsampling rate of 2?

References:

1. [Fixed smooth convolutional layer for avoiding checkerboard artifacts in CNNs](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.02117)
2. [Super-Resolution using Convolutional Neural Networks without Any Checkerboard Artifacts](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.02658)
3. [Checkerboard-Artifact-Free Image-Enhancement Network Considering Local and Global Features](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.12347)